# Emacs won't exit

Tags: linux, emacs

I am new to emacs. I opened a file on centos using:

```
emacs File.java
```

To exit I typed the shortcut C-c but it's not working. It keeps given me:

```
C-c C-c is undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exit the shortcut is C-x C-c.

Read this:
[Emacs Ref Card](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf)

You are getting that undefine because you continously type C-c C-c. If it was define for something and you needed to abort, type : C-g

Comment: thanks I thought C-x and C-c were two seperate options.

Comment: See the Emacs manual (`C-h r`), node [Exiting Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html).

Comment: Type `C-h t` to start the built-in tutorial.